# Generic comparison logic for objects

Tags: c#, object, serialization, comparison

I am working on the back end of a REST API - 
 
For a POST request (in one of the scenarios) I need to validate if the object sent by the user is the same as the one stored in the Db.
**What is an efficient way of comparing two objects in C#?**

PS - I want the comparison logic to **withstand the test of time**, i.e. being a huge team I do not rely on people adding new fields in the IComparable logic. Anyone can add a new property to the object and that would skip the validation test if they do not add that to the comparison logic.

I am thinking of Deserializing the object stored in our database and compare it to the deserialized version of that the user POSTS.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the object have any properties which uniquely identify each instance? Something like a primary key in a database? Or are there any properties which must be unique?

Comment: Yes, there are. How does that help?

Comment: It helps because you only need to compare the properties which are part of the primary key in order to determine uniqueness.

Comment: Aah well, I didn't explain myself clearly then. Let us say for one scenario, i want to make a validation that throws if you try to update any property in the object.

Since this is a POST call, I do not want to call into the update sproc if any property has been modified while my object happens to be in a terminal state. So, it's not just the primary key.

Comment: From the API perspective, I want to let the user know that he cannot modify a sub resource as it is in a terminal state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automagically implement `IComparable<T>` on `T` for ValueObjects (objects for which their identity is all of their fields) is a form of Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP).

[There are various Aspect frameworks for C#.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25366644/1808494)

In this case I would advise you use `PM> Install-Package Equals.Fody`.

To use it is pretty easy.

```
[Equals]
public class Foo
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }        
}
```