# Can I add code to a method via an Attribute?

Tags: c#, annotations, attributes

I want to be able to add some code to the beginning of a method if it has a certain attribute.  For example, I want it to return immediately if it has a particular attribute and it is Wednesday:

```
[Return()]
public void MyMethod()
{
    //If [Return()] attribute and its Wednesday, it returns and never "Does Stuff"
    //Do Stuff
}
```

I have the start to my Attribute, but I cannot figure out how to run the code ahead of the method.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ReturnAttribute : Attribute
{
     public void Return()
     {
         if(Today == Wednesday)
         {
             return;
         }
     {   
}
```

I know the `ReturnAttribute` is incorrect.  I posted that code to show how close (or far) I have come.

How can I insert code at the beginning of a method, if that method is marked with the specified attribute?

Comment: You may want to look at the Fody libraries and see how they work

Comment: You would have to add code to every method that added ```[Return]``` to use reflection to find the attribute, instatiate it and then run it. It would be far simpler to just add a one-line helper method that returned a ```bool``` to the top of the method and return if it's true.

```
public void Blah()
{
    if (Helper.IsItWednesday())
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This technique is all about method interception. Please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366243/intercept-method-calls. Take a close look at the second answer and imagine the line `_stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();` being replaced by "if day not is Wednesday"

Answer (score 0):

### Compile time solution

Perhaps you could try using [ConditionalAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), and set a condition that is never true.  For example....

```
[Conditional("NEVER")]
public static void MyMethod(int x)
{
    //This code will never run
}
```

This will have the *effect* you want, but only at compile time.  Note that this will only work on methods that return `void`.  Not sure what you'd want to do with methods that return something else, since you don't want any code to run, and therefore cannot instantiate any objects to return.

### Run time, cut & paste-able solution

Add a bit of reflection to the top of your method:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

[Return()]
void MyMethod(int x)
{
    var skip = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetCustomAttributes( typeof( ReturnAttribute ), false ).Any();
    if (skip) return;
    //Rest of the code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand how this works (even after reading the linked documentation).  I updated my question to be more clear, as I think your answer only tells a method whether or not it compiles.

Comment: Added a second option for run-time check.